# Yii2 unable to extract message in mongodb

Tags: yii2

Yii2 unable to extract message in mongodb

I want to use mongodb as a message source to store message and translations

Here is my config

```
return [

    'sourcePath' => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
    'languages' => ['zh-CN', 'de'],
    'translator' => 'Yii::t',
    'sort' => false,
    'removeUnused' => false,
    'markUnused' => true,
    'only' => ['*.php'],
    'except' => [
        '.svn',
        '.git',
        '.gitignore',
        '.gitkeep',
        '.hgignore',
        '.hgkeep',
        '/messages',
    ],
    'catalog' => 'app',
    'overwrite' => true,

    /*
    // Message categories to ignore
    'ignoreCategories' => [
        'yii',
    ],
     */


    // 'db' output format is for saving messages to database.
    'format' => 'db',
    // Connection component to use. Optional.
    'db' => 'mongodb',
    // Custom source message table. Optional.
    // 'sourceMessageTable' => '{{%source_message}}',
    // Custom name for translation message table. Optional.
    // 'messageTable' => '{{%message}}',


];
```

main.php

```
 'mongodb' => [
        'class' => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mongotestdb',
    ]
```

Getting this error

exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message '"mongodb" refers to a yii\mongodb\Connection component. yii\db\Connection is expected.'

Comment: Perhaps you can try this :

https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/doc/api/2.1/yii-mongodb-i18n-mongodbmessagesource

Comment: Can't helpful, Already go through with this document...

Comment: Just test whether your connection is established or not then do some operations.            $collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('customer');
$collection->insert(['name' => 'John Smith', 'status' => 1]);

Comment: Connection is established, I had tested it